# How WordPress database manage sections?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I'm introducing articles from the old database to the new WordPress database using the table wp_posts, but I don't know how to indicate to which section each article belongs. It has 5 different sections, and from the old database I know which article goes in what section.

Comment: Which version of WP are you porting it from or is it some other CMS?

Comment: The old database is just a SQL database that use to have an html web page. Current version Wordpress 4.8@happymacarts

Comment: please provide the table layout of your OLD db that indicates the category

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses the following table structures for storing "categories"

`wp_post` joins to `wp_terms` by way of the `wp_term_relationships`

```
SELECT p.id, p.post_title, t.name FROM `wp_posts` p
join `wp_term_relationships` r on r.object_id = p.id 
join `wp_terms` t on t.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
```

You would need to import the categories to the `wp_terms` table 
then you would have to import the relationships into the `wp_term_relationships` table

so if you table structure looked like this:

**id | post_title | post_content | category**

1  | "my first post" | "this is my post " | "news"

2  | "another post"  | "my second post content" | "articles"

you would have to do a few inserts

```
insert into `wp_terms` (name, slug) select category, category from old.posts_table; 
insert into `wp_post` (     
    ID,
    post_author,
    post_date,
    post_date_gmt,
    post_content,
    post_title,
    post_excerpt,
    post_status,
    comment_status,
    ping_status,
    post_password,
    post_name,
    to_ping,
    pinged,
    post_modified,
    post_modified_gmt,
    post_content_filtered,
    post_parent,
    guid,
    menu_order,
    post_type,
    post_mime_type,
    comment_count) select -- all these values need to be populated 
from old.posts_table
```

then you would need to populate the relationship table based on the ids for your "terms"

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much!! @happymacarts

Comment: If this resolved your issue please consider upvoting and accepting the answer